# How to write back to socket in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-integration

I have a spring boot project that uses Spring Integration for TCP communications. I'm sending a request to server, server returns firstly an ACK and then returns actual response. Server wants me to send ACK when I get the response. How can I send this ACK on same socketto indicate that I got the response?

This my connection factory and outbound gateway:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="tcpClientFactory"
                               type="client"
                               host="${host}"
                               port="${port}"
                               so-keep-alive="true"
                               single-use="true"
                               using-nio="true"
                               serializer="messageSerializer"
                               deserializer="messageSerializer"/>

<ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outboundGateway"
                         connection-factory="tcpClientFactory"
                         request-channel="toTcpAdapterChannel"
                         reply-channel="fromTcpAdapterChannel"
                         auto-startup="true"
                         request-timeout="90000"
                         remote-timeout="90000"
                         reply-timeout="90000"/>
```

This is my serialized and deserializer:

```
@Override
public void serialize(byte[] bytes, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        super.serialize(bytes, outputStream);

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream btO = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            super.serialize(bytes, btO);
            logger.debug("Message(Serialized) bytes:" + HexUtils.toHexString(btO.toByteArray()));
        
    }
}

@Override
public byte[] deserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    boolean allMessageRead = false;
    byte[] incomingArray = new byte[0];
    while (!allMessageRead) {
        int length = inputStream.available();
        incomingArray = new byte[length];
        this.read(inputStream, incomingArray, false);
        if (length == 1) {
            logger.info("Available length of inputStream is: {}", length);
            logger.info("Length is 1. Incoming byte: {}", HexUtils.toHexString(incomingArray));
            return null;
        } else if (length > 1) {
            System.out.println("Message DUMP-1! " + HexUtils.toHexString(incomingArray));
            incomingArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(incomingArray, 1, length - 3);
            allMessageRead = true;
        }
    }

    return incomingArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the gateway to send arbitrary messages, only request/reply.

To do what you need, you must use collaborating channel adapters instead.

See the documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#ip-collaborating-adapters

**EDIT**

Alternatively, probably a simpler solution would be to use connection interceptors. Your interceptor can send the ack when the result is received.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#ip-interceptors

Comment: I read the link but couldn't understand clearly. Should I change tcp-outbound-gateway to tcp-outbound-channel-adapter and add tcp-inbound-channel-adapter? In this case how can I use same socket to send ACK?

Comment: I think it might be rather complicated; see the edit to my answer for another option.